# onClick event in android tabwidget

Tags: android, android-tabhost, onclicklistener

i am working with tabview. i have 3 tabs in my tabwidget view. Below is my MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
TabHost host;
Intent intent;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Resources res = getResources();
    host = (TabHost) findViewById (R.id.tabhost);
    host.setup();

    TabSpec tspecMovies = host.newTabSpec("tag1");
    // tspecMovies.setContent(R.id.tab1);
    tspecMovies.setIndicator("Movies", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.movie_icon));
    host.addTab(tspecMovies);

    TabSpec tspecTv = host.newTabSpec("tag2");
    // tspecTv.setContent(R.id.tab2);
    tspecTv.setIndicator("TV",  res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tv_icon));
    host.addTab(tspecTv);

    TabSpec tspecEvents = host.newTabSpec("tag3");
    // tspecEvents.setContent(R.id.tab3);
    tspecEvents.setIndicator("Events",  res.getDrawable(R.drawable.event_icon));
    host.addTab(tspecEvents);


    }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
   }
}
```

I have 3 different Activities for each tabs which contains the tab contents. I want to know how do i call these activities on onClick event when the tab is clicked.

Comment: check it out my answer.

Answer (score 0):

find below code for that.

```
    host.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {

                    if(getString(R.string.tab1).equals(tabId)){

                        //your activity 1
                        // R.string.tab1 is the Id given to tab using values/string.xml file

                    }else if(getString(R.string.tab2).equals(tabId)){

                        // your activity 2
                    }
                }
   }
```

Comment: call method instead of starting new activity and then display in tab area.

Comment: its for OnChange listener. i want to call activity for OnClick listener

Answer (score 0):

You have to set intent to each tab..

use this code

```
// Android tab                                      //activity which you want to call  
Intent intentAndroid = new Intent().setClass(this, AndroidActivity.class);
TabSpec tabSpecAndroid = tabHost
      .newTabSpec("Android")
      .setIndicator("", ressources.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_android_config))
      .setContent(intentAndroid);
```

For more info [Complete Tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-tablayout-example/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass **tabspect** with intent

```
TabSpec tspecMovies = host.newTabSpec("tag1");
    // tspecMovies.setContent(R.id.tab1);
    tspecMovies.setIndicator("Movies", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.movie_icon));
    host.addTab(tspecMovies)
   Intent moviesintent=new Intent(this, MoviesActivity.class);
   moviesintent.setContent(videosIntent);
```

You can refer this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/08/android-tab-layout-tutorial/).

I hope You can learn very well.